# Variable input function scipy.curve_fit

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am working on peak deconvolution of my experimental data and I would like to generate a Python script where I can easily vary the equations for the non-linear curve fitting/peak deconvolution. Using Gaussian curves and a linear offset, scipy.optimize.curve_fit works well with the following code:

```
def Combined(x,*params):
    off = Linear(x,params[0],params[1])
    peak1 = Gaussian(x,params[2],params[3],params[4])
    peak2 = Gaussian(x,params[5],params[6],params[7])
    peak3 = Gaussian(x,params[8],params[9],params[10])
    return off + peak1 + peak2 + peak3

popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(Combined, data[10][0], data[10][1], method='lm', check_finite=True, p0=[0.1, 0.1, 115, 508.33, 7.1,130, 508.33, 7.1, 165.84, 508.33, 7.1])
```

All equations are previously defined in a function:

```
def ZeroOrder(x,a):
    return a

def Linear(x,a,b):
    return a+b*x

def SecondOrder(x,a,b,c):
    return a+b*x+c*x**2
```

I would like to create a function as `Combine(x,baseline='ZeroOrder',peak1='Gaussian',peak2='Gaussian',peak3='Gaussian')` where I can easily assign different peak functions instead of having to create a specific function for each combination. In my understanding however the curve_fit function is quite rigid and requires an input function as `Combined(x,*params)`. How can I change my code so it will work in the desired function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this situation, I would use something more versatile, like f_min from scipy.
Here's a sample of how you could make a generic regressor for experimental data.

I created an abstract class just to define an interface to a shape function, this helps to create a more generic approach

In the example below, the coefficients obtained by the solver aren't the same of the original function, but for determined domain the result function meets the convergence criteria, this must be because there is a lot of degrees of freedom for the function I created.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import List

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fmin

from pprint import pprint

class ShapeFunction(ABC):
    def __init__(self, params_count: int):
        self.params_count = params_count
        self.params = [0] * params_count

    @property
    def params(self):
        return self.__params

    @params.setter
    def params(self, params: List[float]):
        if len(params) != self.params_count:
            raise ValueError(f"params count must be {self.params_count}")
        self.__params = params

    @abstractmethod
    def evaluate(self, t: List[float]) -> List[float]:
        pass


class Gaussian(ShapeFunction):
    def __init__(self):
        params_count = 3
        super().__init__(params_count)

    def evaluate(self, t: List[float]) -> List[float]:
        return self.Gaussian(t, *self.params)

    @staticmethod
    def Gaussian(x, mu, sigma, scale):
        return scale/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-0.5*((x-mu)/sigma)**2)


class ZeroOrder(ShapeFunction):
    def __init__(self):
        params_count = 1
        super().__init__(params_count)

    def evaluate(self, t: List[float]) -> List[float]:
        return self.ZeroOrder(t, *self.params)

    @staticmethod
    def ZeroOrder(x, a):
        return a


class Linear(ShapeFunction):
    def __init__(self):
        params_count = 2
        super().__init__(params_count)

    def evaluate(self, t: List[float]) -> List[float]:
        return self.Linear(t, *self.params)

    @staticmethod
    def Linear(x, a, b):
        return a+b*x


class Quadratic(ShapeFunction):
    def __init__(self):
        params_count = 3
        super().__init__(params_count)

    def evaluate(self, t: List[float]) -> List[float]:
        return self.Quadratic(t, *self.params)

    @staticmethod
    def Quadratic(x, a, b, c):
        return a+b*x+c*x**2


f1 = Gaussian()
f1.params = [0, 1, 10]

f2 = ZeroOrder()
f2.params = [1]

f3 = Linear()
f3.params = [1, 1]

f4 = Quadratic()
f4.params = [1, 1, 1]


shape_functions = [f1, f2, f3, f4]
coefs_count = sum([func.params_count for func in shape_functions])

original_coefs = []
for func in shape_functions:
    original_coefs.extend(func.params)

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
sample = f1.evaluate(x) + f2.evaluate(x) + f3.evaluate(x) + f4.evaluate(x)


def cost_function(coefs: list[float], *params):
    funcs: List[ShapeFunction] = params[0]
    parametric_values: List[float] = params[1]
    obj_y: List[float] = params[2]

    y = [0] * len(parametric_values)

    for func in funcs:
        func.params = coefs[:func.params_count]
        y += func.evaluate(parametric_values)

        coefs = coefs[func.params_count:]

    return np.sum((y - obj_y)**2)


x0 = [1] * coefs_count
solution = fmin(cost_function, x0, args=(shape_functions, x, sample))


for sol, coef in zip(solution, original_coefs):
    print(f"Original: {coef:.2f} -> solution: {sol:.2f}")


y_sol = np.sum([func.evaluate(x) for func in shape_functions], axis=0)

plt.plot(x, sample, label="Original")
plt.plot(x, y_sol, label="Solution", alpha=0.5, marker=".")

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```