# Fmin not converging peak fitting

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I am trying to implement a Gaussian peak deconvolution function on my experimental data (Temperature_K,alpha_dt), where I try to deconvolute with three Gaussian curves. In a previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69814773/variable-input-function-scipy-curve-fit) I was recommended to use classes for my function definition and to use fmin() instead of curve_fit() (both from the scipy.optimize package). I tried to implement the advised solution but I don't get the code running with my own experimental input. With the current code fmin() for some reason does not converge. I believe it has to do with the passing of the x-data in my Gaussian.evaluate function since it always returns an arrays of zeros. It might be obvious but I don't see what is the issue and how to solve it.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
from scipy.stats import norm

#Experimental data:
Temperature_K = np.linspace(323,523,2222)
alpha_dt = norm.pdf(x_axis,380,10)+norm.pdf(x_axis,400,20)+norm.pdf(x_axis,450,20)

class Gaussian():
    def __init__(self,params=None):
        self.params = params

    def evaluate(self,t,params):
        return self.Gaussian(t, *self.params) #t = Temperature vector (given), params = coefficients to be optimized

    @staticmethod
    def Gaussian(x, xc, A, w):
        return (A*np.exp((-4*np.log(2)*(x-xc)**2)/w**2))/(w*np.sqrt(np.pi/(4*np.log(2))))

def cost_function(coeffs,T,y_obj):
    y_eval = f1.evaluate(T,coeffs[0:3])+f2.evaluate(T,coeffs[3:6])+f3.evaluate(T,coeffs[6:9])
    return np.sum((y_eval - y_obj)**2)

f1 = Gaussian()
f1.params = [380,500,7] #Assign initial guesses to parameter values

f2 = Gaussian()
f2.params = [400,500,7]

f3 = Gaussian()
f3.params = [450,500,7]

x0 = f1.params + f2.params+f3.params #Combine initial guesses to function input

popt = opt.fmin(cost_function,x0,args=(Temperature_K,alpha_dt)) #Optimize parameters by minimizing cost function
#Temperature_K = experimental x-data, alpha_dt = experimental y-data
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `evaluate` function doesn't use the `params` argument only `self.params`, therefore you might not be optimizing the function you want. To fix this change your `evaluate`function to the below:

```py
@staticmethod # <- static because you are not using self anywhere
def evaluate(t, params):
        return Gaussian.Gaussian(t, *params) #  <- Use the provided params argument
```

Some other coding issues:

1. Your exampe code does not run, please provide a working code.
2. You are not setting or using `self.params` anywhere
3. Your cost function uses non-local variable

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I changed the lines in my code but it still doesn't converge. Moreover, if I test:
```
f1 = Gaussian()
f1.params = [100,1,7]
x = f1.evaluate(Temperature_K,[100,1,7]) 
```
it still returns a vector of zeros instead of the curve what it should be.

Comment: here are issues with the code you uploaded (e.g. `Temperature_K` is not defined anywhere), so could only guess here why you get the results.

Comment: It was an array defined before, I edited it into the question.